# OverQuotaMapError for Google Places autocomplete with unrestricted API key

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api, google-places-api

I am trying to have google places autocomplete on an form-input. I keep getting following error:

```
["Google Maps JavaScript API error: OverQuotaMapError
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#over-quota-map-error"]
```

However I think there are no restrictions in the Google Console API for the keys I use. Both Locations API and Maps Javascript API are enabled. Tried also making new api-key.

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/musicformellons/tm01jo37/2/) (which code is provided by Google itself so should be ok) shows similar behaviour when a key is entered, so first replace `YOUR_GOOGLE_KEY` for a valid Google Key (I also used a completely unrestricted key...)

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_GOOGLE_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap&solution_channel=GMP_QB_addressselection_v1_cA" async defer></script>
```

As soon as you start using the Address inputbox the above described error will appear.

My questions:

1. Can someone confirm the fiddle works with a proper google key (i.e. my google key is the problem...)?
2. If (1) shows the key is indeed the problem, what is wrong with my key?

Answer (score 0):

The api key was indeed not valid.

To fix the error for Places Autocomplete requests using the JavaScript Autocomplete widget:

1. Go to the Quotas page of your project
2. Click on "All Google Maps Platform APIs", and select the Maps JavaScript API
3. Click the down arrow to open the Map Loads section
4. Scroll down past the two graphs, and click the pencil icon on the "Map loads per minute" quota. Change the quota limit from 0 to a higher number, up to 30000.
5. Click the pencil icon for "Map loads per minute per user", and change the limit from 0 to a higher number, up to 300.

If you are testing a new web application, you may want to leave the "Map loads per day" quota set to 100.

So apparently when you use autocomplete for places you also need to enable 'map loads'. Not really obvious, but works now.